# Consistently place an arrow relative to a plot regardless of that plot's range

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to make several copies of the same kind of plot and would like all of them to have a little arrow below the x-axis to help the reader. However, the only way I have found of placing such an arrow is the geom_segment element which requires me to specify start and end points which change according to the range of data.

Ideally, if I could access the values at which ggplot2 places tickmarks along the x-axis, that would solve my problem as I could use those as start and end points.

A minimal example is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(names = rownames(mtcars)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c("mpg", "cyl", "disp"), names_to = "type", values_to = "val") %>% 
  select(names:val)

data1 <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(names = rownames(mtcars)) %>% 
  filter(mpg > 15) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c("mpg", "cyl", "disp"), names_to = "type", values_to = "val") %>% 
  select(names:val)

facet_df <- data.frame(
  type = "mpg"
)

plot_func <- function(df) {
  df %>% ggplot +
    geom_point(aes(x = val, y = names)) +
    facet_wrap(facets = vars(type), ncol = 3, scales = "free_x") +
    geom_segment(data = facet_df, x = 11, xend = 14, y = -1, yend = -1,
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(3, "pt"))) +
    coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
}

plot_func(data)
plot_func(data1)
```

plot_func(data)

[image]

plot_func(data1)

[image]

Comment: you want the arrow below `val` or above the `val` ?

Comment: On the second plot you want the arrow to be placed between 15 and 20?

Comment: @shafee above where it says "val", preferably just below the actual values.

Comment: @zx8754 Yes, either spanning the same numerical range or the same range in cm.

Comment: Getting the range or the values of the first two breaks could be achieved via `breaks <- scales::breaks_extended()(df[df$type == "mpg", "val", drop = TRUE])[1:2]`. The tricky part IMHO is to place the arrow nicely in the vertical direction, i.e. choosing the `y`s.

Comment: @stefan I can probably achieve that by counting the number of elements that will be plotted vertically. Thanks for the tip on the tickmarks! :)

Comment: @stefan it appears my minimal example was too minimal. The true plot is with errorbars and the breaks_extended function does not work correctly in that case.

Comment: @stefan Some further investigation shows that the breaks_extended function and its cousin layer_scales(plot, 1, 3)$x$break_positions() which does about the same thing only fail when given the data I actually care about, but seem to work fine in the test data I've bee able to look into.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

data <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(names = rownames(mtcars)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c("mpg", "cyl", "disp"), names_to = "type", values_to = "val") %>% 
  select(names:val)

data1 <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(names = rownames(mtcars)) %>% 
  filter(mpg > 15) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c("mpg", "cyl", "disp"), names_to = "type", values_to = "val") %>% 
  select(names:val)

facet_df <- data.frame(
  type = "mpg"
)

plot_func <- function(df) {
  p <- df %>% ggplot +
    geom_point(aes(x = val, y = names)) +
    facet_wrap(facets = vars(type), ncol = 3, scales = "free_x") +
    # xlab(expression(atop("val", symbol('\256'))))+
    labs(
     x = NULL
    ) +
    coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
    theme(
      plot.margin=unit(c(0.3,0.3,1.4,0.3), "cm")
    )
  print(p)
  grid.lines(x = c(0.4, 0.7), 
             y = c(0.08, 0.08),
             arrow = arrow(type="open", ends="last", angle = 40,
                          length=unit(3,"mm")))
  grid.text(x = 0.58, y = 0.035, label = "val", )
}

plot_func(data)
```

[image]

```r
plot_func(data1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Does this work for You??

Comment: Unfortunately not. My minimal example was a bit too minimal. My third facet is really a spread around 0, and I want arrows on either side of 0 which is not going to be in the same spot every time I run the function, so I need to be able to define the arrows relative to zero.